# Moneris On site Processing for Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Someone has any recommendation for an extension to integrate with Moneris on site processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company has hired a development team to build us a new site on 2.0, and this is the major problem we've run in to. Either build on 1.9 with Moneris integration (which we need), or wait for Moneris to build a 2.0 plugin and delay the site launch.

The company we've hired is telling me that Moneris is working on this, but will not specify a release date (could be weeks or months). We've looked in to other options, such as [off-site Moneris processing](http://www.monerisusa.com/payment-processing-services/point-of-sale/eselect-plus/~/media/Files/eSel%20Docs/MonerisHostedPaypageUS.ashx) as an interim solution. Magento also comes bundled with [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) as an alternative payment gateway solution. To the best of my knowledge, there is no Magento 2.0 extension for Moneris on-site processing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I would appreciate if you find anything to post here. I will do the same.